# Function object to pass std::get around as an argument to functions

Tags: c++, lambda, template-meta-programming, c++20, function-object

My intention is to write a getter for the `N`th element of whatever `std::get` can take as argument once it's instantiated with a specific `N`.

In other words, `std::get<N>` cannot be passed around because it's not a function object, but a function templated on the type of the argument it takes.

Is it possible to define an object `getNth` such that `std::invoke(getNth<1>, whatever);` makes sense and is actually equivalent to `getNth<1>(whatever)`?

The most I could get working is `std::invoke(getNth<1>(), whatever);`, by defining `getNth` this way:

```cpp
template<int N>
auto getNth() {
    return [](auto const& x){ return std::get<N>(x); };
};
```

Is it possible to avoid having to use the two parenthesis?

I thought templated lambdas could be useful, but they can't as they are classes with a templated `operator()` just like generic non-templated lambdas (with only difference that with the former we can have the type of the parameters be non-identity functions of the template parameters).

Instead, for `std::invoke(getNth<1>, whatever);` to be meaningful, I think `getNth` should not be a template function, nor a template class, but something else... which doesn't take parenthesis after the closing `>`, as it happens for [variable templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template).

However, based on the bullet point at the top of [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates), probably I'm looking for something which the syntax simply does not offer. Is this the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> which doesn't take parenthesis after the closing `>`, as it happens for variable templates.

Exactly, a variable template is just what you want:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

template<int N>
auto getNth = [](auto const& x){ return std::get<N>(x); };

int main() {
    auto whatever = std::tuple{1, 2, 3};
    return std::invoke(getNth<1>, whatever);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7xzeEd)

Comment: Oh, lord, it's obvious! A lambda is a variable! I feel so stupid now...

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know any library that provides such a function object?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, which is a shame. Oddly enough, in Boost.Hana `at_c` (which is designed for its own tuple but can work with std::tuple via an adaptor) "is an overloaded function, not a function object. Hence, it can't be passed to higher-order algorithms. This is done for compile-time performance reasons". https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Iterable.html#ga4cb99cfbef936cb267e76f66f40f529c